# Formatting numbers with currency or percent symbols with textwatcher

Tags: android, format, currency, textwatcher

I've searched SO on how to format numbers with currency or percent symbols while using textwatcher, but still can't get things to work. I tried using the DecimalFormat method amongst others as it would seem straight forward, but I guess since the textwatch is running constantly, my app crashes. Here's a snippet of what I have. I just need textViewproceeds.setText(addProceeds()) to format as currency or percent. Thanks.

```
editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);

editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

boolean editing = false;


        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                  int count) {


        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(!editing) {
            editing = true;
            editText1.removeTextChangedListener(this);
                 editText3.setText(currency.format(Double.parseDouble(addProceeds())));
            editText1.addTextChangedListener(this);
            editing = false;
        }



        }
    });
    editText2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
       boolean editing = false;
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                  int count) {


        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(!editing) {
                editing = true;
                editText1.removeTextChangedListener(this);
                editText3.setText(currency.format(Double.parseDouble(addProceeds())));
                editText1.addTextChangedListener(this);
                editing = false;
            }

        }
    });
}


    private String addProceeds() {
    Double num1;
    Double num2;

    if (editText1.getText().toString() != "" && editText1.getText().length() > 0) {
        num1 = Double.parseDouble("0" + editText1.getText().toString());
    } else {
        num1 = Double.valueOf(0);
    }
    if (editText2.getText().toString() != "" && editText2.getText().length() > 0) {
        num2 = Double.parseDouble("0" + editText2.getText().toString());
    } else {
        num2 = Double.valueOf(0);
    }

    return Double.toString(num1 + num2);
}
```

So far the following formats currency fine as a final calculation of a single editText field, but doesn't work while numbers are being inputted due to the infinite loop.

```
           //Put below somewhere at class level
           DecimalFormat currency = new DecimalFormat("$###,##0.00");

           boolean editing = false;
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(!editing) {
            editing = true;
            editText1.removeTextChangedListener(this);
            editText3.setText(currency.format(Double.parseDouble(addProceeds())));
            editText1.addTextChangedListener(this);
            editing = false;
        }
```

Comment: please add your xml file.

Comment: Since `setText()` ends up triggering the `TextWatcher` again, you're getting yourself into a recursive loop (hello stack overflow :)). A naive solution would be to guard the call with i.e. a boolean, or temporarily remove the textwatcher, and then re-add it again after setting the text. A neater solution would be to implement `afterTextChanged()`, from which it's valid to modify the `Editable` parameter - still be careful not to get yourself running in circles though.